# wpf，my datagrid binding datatable，but when I change the column order of datagrid By dragging columns，the datatable column not update？

Tags: wpf, datatable, datagrid

binding is two way，How to update the column order of datatable by changing the column order of DataGrid？

Comment: You will have to add here what you tried, your xaml and viewmodel, and where did you encounter your problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using  Event
You can solve your problem using `ColumnDisplayIndexChanged` event.

```cs
dataGrid1.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += DataGrid1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
```

And within this event, you can see the index value of the changed column.
`e.Column.DisplayIndex`

```cs
private void DataGrid1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
{
    int changedIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
}
```

Finaly, you can change the column index in DataTable

```cs
table.Columns[e.Column.ColumnName].SetOrdinal(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
```

> And you should write the content as sincerely as you can, like other people's advice. It's not a privilege to ask questions. (I ignored this and eventually lost my right to ask questions. So don't repeat the same mistake as me and use your questions preciously!)